# Writing an If statement for the condition of a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a basic Graphics User Interface where if the user clicks "move" 
then a div (yellow rectangle) moves across the screen.

However, I want there to be an event based on Where the rectangle is on the page. In example, If the div is at 400px (right) then alert "hey", else, move the div.

```html
here is the moving div

<html>
<head>
    <title>Move Div</title>
    
    <script language ="javascript">
        <!--
            function MoveDiv()
            {
                div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
                
                
                div.style.left = parseInt(div.style.left) + 100 + "px";
            }
        //-->
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Move Div" onclick="MoveDiv()" />
    <div id="myDiv" style="border: 10px solid black; background-color: Yellow; width: 100px; height: 30px; position: absolute; top: 1px; left: 100px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
here is the moving div

<html>
<head>
    <title>Move Div</title>
    
    <script language ="javascript">
        <!--
            function MoveDiv(){
           if ($('#myDiv').css == marginTop: '-=15px' ) {
                div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
                
                
                div.style.left =  parseInt(div.style.left) + 100 + "px";
            }}
        //-->
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Move Div" onclick="MoveDiv()" />
    <div id="myDiv" style="border: 10px solid black; background-color: Yellow; width: 100px; height: 30px; position: absolute; top: 1px; left: 100px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

errors mostly because im not sure on the syntax :(

Comment: instead of `function MoveDiv()` try  `function MoveDiv() {` - a function body must be in `{}` - see how you omitted them from the first example

Comment: There are a lot:1. Encapsulate in {} the function
2. do not write ; after condition
3. do not write text before <htm><body> - eg: "here is the moving div"
4. this condition doesn't exists: ($('#myDiv').css == marginTop: '-=15px' )

Comment: Don't write  ; in if condition

Comment: think i corrected those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope its help you

You must use var (let, const) when create a new variable

I added CONSTANTS for easy configuration,

`isDivCanMoveForward` for your:

> Where the rectangle is on the page. In example, If the div is at 400px (right) then alert "hey", else, move the div.

```js
var MAX_POSITION_OF_DIV_NODE = 400;
var STEP_OF_DIV_NODE = 100;

var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");

var currentPositionOfDivNode = parseInt(div.style.left, 10);

function MoveDiv() {
  currentPositionOfDivNode += STEP_OF_DIV_NODE; // increment

  if (!isDivCanMoveForward()) {
    return; // stop functinon when div have max position
  }

  div.style.left = currentPositionOfDivNode + "px";
}

function isDivCanMoveForward() {
  if (currentPositionOfDivNode > MAX_POSITION_OF_DIV_NODE) {
    currentPositionOfDivNode = MAX_POSITION_OF_DIV_NODE // set max of value

    alert('hey')// user message

    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Move Div</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <input type="button" value="Move Div" onclick="MoveDiv()" />
      <div id="myDiv" style="border: 10px solid black; background-color: Yellow; width: 100px; height: 30px; position: absolute; top: 1px; left: 100px;"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please use StackSnippets when answering or asking. Also keep in mind that code-only answers like yours are hard to track the changes in comparison to the code OP presented. Always explain what you changed and why.

Comment: Hmm, okay I added all of this.
I hope now you like my answer